# D3 V5 zoom y axis but pan x axis on drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

AIM:
1)Draw x and y axis
2)Zoom and pan x axis when mouse is on x axis
3)zoom y axis alone when mouse in on y axis and above x axis
4)pan x axis when dragged the mouse above x-axis

i am able to do first 3 but unable to do the 4th one as my y axis zoom(at y axis and above x axis) interrupts with my xaxis zoom call while panning above my x-axis[Check image for x axis , y axis and above x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2lIb.png)

This bug is killing me for sometime.

Comment: Please add your code, also, not sure if this is what you are looking for: http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for. Please see the image posted, while zooming on x axis I should be able to zoom only on x axis.  on zooming in on area above x axis I should zoom in only y axis. on dragging/panning on x axis and above x axis I should be able to drag only x axis.